# Getting the access token for Microsoft Graph API without using Client Secret Key

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I want to call Microsoft Graph API but before that i require the Access token. Can anybody tell me how to get the access token **without using the "Client Secret Key"** in C#

Answer (score 0):

The steps are documented on the Graph pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

To get a token without a secret (credential) means that you are creating a public client application. There are several public client implementations you could use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS